# Как в jsf (primefaces) выбрать строку(row) в panelGrid

Tags: java, gui, jsf, primefaces, grid

Кто сможет подсказать, как у грида в JSF (primefaces) хоть как ни будь организовать выбор записи (строки).
Любым способом получить значение var в которое ткнули мышкой. Для населения грида используется `ui:repeat`.
P.S. Очень не хочется рассматривать вариант с добавлением столбца с `p:selectOneRadio`.

Comment: Может использовать `DataTable` - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml?

Comment: не, не подходит к сожалению

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `varStatus.index` и передавать его как параметр ajax запроса, например через `remoteCommand`.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="comm" action="#{bean.method()}"/>

<ui:repeat varStatus="status">
  <component onclick="comm([{name:'nameIndex', value: #{status.index}}])"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ )) на досуге попробую, но т.к. долго не мог сообразить как это сделать с гридом перепилил все на dataTable